# Anyone know of a log viewer web application for java?

Tags: java, web-applications, logging

Im looking for a web based log viewer that can be deployed to a tomcat webserver. Does anyone know of any good web based log viewers

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/base/Documentation/latest/Installation/Splunksarchitectureandwhatgetsinstalled) which satisfies **your web-based log viewer criteria**.

However, **It is not a web app which can be deployed on Tomcat** or any web server, but it runs as it's own web server at localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

Like Splunk, as mentioned in another answer but free.. [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/)

Seems to do most of the same kinds of thing, only without an epic pricetag.